# Efficient way to add/ append huge files

Tags: bash, shell, perl, sed, substr

Below is a shell script that is written to process a huge file. It typically reads a fixed length file line by line, perform substring and append into another file as a delimited file. It works perfectly, but it is too slow.

```
array=() # Create array
       while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]] # Read a line
       do
      coOrdinates="$(echo -e "${line}" | grep POSITION | cut -d'(' -f2 | cut -d')' -f1 | cut -d':' -f1,2)"
          if   [[ -z "${coOrdinates// }" ]];
          then
  echo "Not adding"
          else
  array+=("$coOrdinates")
  fi
       done < "$1_CTRL.txt"

while read -r line;
  do
          result='"'
          for e in "${array[@]}"
          do
          SUBSTRING1=`echo "$e" | sed 's/.*://'`
          SUBSTRING=`echo "$e" | sed 's/:.*//'`
          result1=`perl -e "print substr('$line', $SUBSTRING,$SUBSTRING1)"`
          result1="$(echo -e "${result1}" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')"
          result=$result$result1'"'',''"'
          done
          echo $result >> $1_1.txt
  done < "$1.txt"
```

Earlier, i had used the cut command and changed as above, but there is no improvement in the time taken.
Can please suggest what kind of changes can be done to improve the time taken for processing.. 
Thanks in advance

Update:

Sample content of the input file :

```
XLS01G702012        000034444132412342134
```

Control File :

```
OPTIONS (DIRECT=TRUE, ERRORS=1000, rows=500000) UNRECOVERABLE
  load data
   CHARACTERSET 'UTF8'
   TRUNCATE
   into table icm_rls_clientrel2_hg
   trailing nullcols
   (
   APP_ID POSITION(1:3) "TRIM(:APP_ID)",
   RELATIONSHIP_NO POSITION(4:21) "TRIM(:RELATIONSHIP_NO)"
  )
```

Output file:

```
"LS0","1G702012 0000"
```

Comment: Try to do everything in Perl, it should speed it up

Comment: If you used less subshells and external utilities for trivial pattern matching and string manipulation, things would be a lot faster (yet, Bash will still be very slow for processing huge files).

Comment: You really don't want to have to create 2 processes for `cut` another 3 processes for `sed` and a `grep` and then start a whole `perl` interpreter for every single line of your file... try and start a single `perl` script that internally reads the lines and processes them.

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there to get some hints: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: You need to show some sample input and output.

Comment: @glennjackman Updated the question with sample input and expected output

Comment: What is your idea of a "huge" file? Are we talking about terabytes of data here?

Comment: @Borodin a million records typically.

Comment: So it's about 50MB? That's far from huge: you could easily read the whole thing into memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest, with pure bash and to avoid subshells:

```
if [[ $line =~ POSITION ]] ; then      # grep POSITION 
    coOrdinates="${line#*(}"           # cut -d'(' -f2
    coOrdinates="${coOrdinates%)*}"    # cut -d')' -f1
    coOrdinates="${coOrdinates/:/ }"   # cut -d':' -f1,2
    if   [[ -z "${coOrdinates// }" ]]; then
        echo "Not adding"
    else
        array+=("$coOrdinates")
    fi
fi
```

more efficient, by gniourf_gniourf :

```
if [[ $line =~ POSITION\(([[:digit:]]+):([[:digit:]])\) ]]; then 
    array+=( "${BASH_REMATCH[*]:1:2}" )
fi
```

similarly:

```
SUBSTRING1=${e#*:} # $( echo "$e" | sed 's/.*://' )
SUBSTRING= ${e%:*} # $( echo "$e" | sed 's/:.*//' )

# to confirm, I don't know perl substr 
result1=${line:$SUBSTRING:$SUBSTRING1} # $( perl -e "print substr('$line', $SUBSTRING,$SUBSTRING1)" )


#result1= # "$(echo -e "${result1}" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')"
# trim, if nécessary?
result1="${result1%${result1##*[^[:space:]]}}"    # right
result1="${result1#${result1%%[^[:space:]]*}}"    # left
```

gniourf_gniourf suggest having the grep out of the loop:

```
while read ...; do
 ...
done < <(grep POSITION ...)
```

for extra efficiency: while/read loops are very slow in Bash, so prefiltering as much as possible will speed up the process quite a lot.

Comment: You might as well use regexes all the way through: `if [[ $line =~ POSITION\(([[:digit:]]+):([[:digit:]])\) ]]; then array+=( "${BASH_REMATCH[*]:1:2}" ); fi` or something similar...

Comment: Or you could also suggest having the `grep` out of the loop: `while read ...; do ...; done < <(grep POSITION ...)` for extra efficiency: `while/read` loops are very slow in Bash, so prefiltering as much as possible will speed up the process quite a lot.

Comment: Thanks , was able to process in less than 2 mins.

Comment: and what was the initial time, approximately?

Comment: More than 45 mins earlier.

Answer (score 5):

perl:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

# read the control file
my $ctrl;
{
    local $/ = "";
    open my $fh, "<", shift @ARGV;
    $ctrl = <$fh>;
    close $fh;
}
my @positions = ( $ctrl =~ /\((\d+):(\d+)\)/g );

# read the data file
open my $fh, "<", shift @ARGV;
while (<$fh>) {
    my @words;
    for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@positions); $i += 2) {
        push @words, substr($_, $positions[$i], $positions[$i+1]);
    }
    say join ",", map {qq("$_")} @words;
}
close $fh;
```

```
perl parse.pl x_CTRL.txt x.txt
```

```
"LS0","1G702012        00003"
```

Different results from what you requested:

- in the `POSITION(m:n)` syntax of the control file, is `n` a length or an 
  index?
- in the data file, are those spaces or tabs?

Comment: Very elegant indeed.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Answer**

Here is a version where I parse the control file with `awk`, save the character positions and then use those when parsing the input file:

```
awk '
/APP_ID/ {
     sub(/\).*/,"")   # Strip closing parenthesis and all that follows
     sub(/^.*\(/,"")  # Strip everything up to opening parenthesis
     split($0,a,":")  # Extract the two character positions separated by colon into array "a"
     next
   }
/RELATIONSHIP/ {      
     sub(/\).*/,"")      # Strip closing parenthesis and all that follows
     sub(/^.*\(/,"")     # Strip everything up to opening parenthesis
     split($0,b,"[():]") # Extract character positions into array "b"
     next
   }

FNR==NR{next}

{ f1=substr($0,a[1]+1,a[2]); f2=substr($0,b[1]+1,b[2]); printf("\"%s\",\"%s\"\n",f1,f2)}
' ControlFile InputFile
```

---

**Original Answer**

Not a complete, rigorous answer, but this should give you an idea of how to do the extraction with `awk` once you have the POSITION parameters from the control file:

```
awk -v a=2 -v b=3 -v c=5 -v d=21 '{f1=substr($0,a,b); f2=substr($0,c,d); printf("\"%s\",\"%s\"\n",f1,f2)}' InputFile
```

**Sample Output**

```
"LS0","1G702012        00003"
```

Try running that on your large input file to get an idea of the performance, then tweak the output. Reading the control file is not at all time-critical so don't bother with optimising that.

Comment: Ran your updated answer and it completed in a short time. But, the control file which i shared as example has two fields , but there are other files which might have more than two fields. Trying to change further.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the (slow) while loop , you can use `cut` and `paste`

```
#!/bin/bash    
inFile=${1:-checkHugeFile}.in
ctrlFile=${1:-checkHugeFile}_CTRL.txt
outFile=${1:-checkHugeFile}.txt
cat /dev/null > $outFile

typeset -a array # Create array
while read -r line # Read a line
do
    coOrdinates="${line#*(}"
    coOrdinates="${coOrdinates%%)*}"
    [[ -z "${coOrdinates// }" ]] && { echo "Not adding"; continue; }
    array+=("$coOrdinates")
done < <(grep POSITION "$ctrlFile"  )
echo coOrdinates: "${array[@]}"

for e in "${array[@]}"
do
    nr=$((nr+1))
    start=${e%:*}
    len=${e#*:}
    from=$(( start + 1 ))
    to=$(( start + len + 1 ))
    cut -c$from-$to $inFile > ${outFile}.$nr
done
paste $outFile.* | sed -e 's/^/"/' -e 's/\t/","/' -e 's/$/"/' >${outFile}
rm $outFile.[0-9]
```